# Critical error in execution LoadRunner Controller with SAP GUI

Tags: controller, loadrunner, sap-gui, vugen

I am experimenting a rare error when executing an script recorded with LoadRunner Vugen in LoadRunner Controller. Specifically, I am working with Controller SAP and SAP GUI load generators. The error comes suddenly, in the middle of execution, sometimes at the minute 10, or 5, or... but normally at the minute 40 or so...
The execution takes about 1 hour.

The error is:

> Error: The remote host's status is 'Failed'. Check the remote host machine.    [MsgId: MERR-29722]

And when it occurs, at the same second appears X more errors with

> Abnormal termination, caused by mdrv process termination

and directly X vusers leave the scenario, going to "Error" status. Not all vusers, only a number of vusers, like 12, 16, or 30. Other vusers continue the scenario.

It happens normally in this script, regardless high load and low load of vusers; the remote host seems OK, because CPU and RAM are fine, so.. I don't know what is happening... The script have some C code too, but even the last execution the error appeared at minute 2, when C code (do-while) yet not executed (the script takes about 11 min to complete).

I have function `lr_continue_on_error();` configured in script to avoid punctual errors on execution, and works fine for everything, except this serious error...

I have searched information about this error and there isn't a result in Google about this.

Please, is there someone that have any idea about this rare error? It's very important to me to resolve this...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check that the version of the load generator is matched to the controller, down to the major.minor (Patch) level.  Ensure that you have all of the prerequisites for SAP thick client installed on the load generators.  Finally SAPGUI is heavy on the Windows GDI stack resources.  So, if you can plop a very high end video card in your load generator then you can expand the available GDI stack resources and shore up the stability of your SAPGUi users.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked version of my host controller and the version of controller and vugen of remote host (load generator) and are the same: 12.01.0.0 (major.minor (patch), i think). The load generators have 12gb ram, Intel Xeon E7 2.60ghz cpu, and windows server 2008 r2 standard,  so i think the prerequisites are Ok, but in vmware i think (they're on outside servers to me). Maybe the problem is the GDI? Not enough video card to open many graphic interface sapgui on this machine? Thank you so much! @JamesPulley